# Multiple modes in a Qt Quick QML Window?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

Suppose I have a QML Window that contains a bunch of different controls:

```
Window {
  ...

  TextEdit { ... }
  CheckBox { ... }
  Button { ... }
  etc
```

}

Now I want my window to change "mode" on a certain event, and display a completely different set of controls.

Imagine its part of a multi-screen form.  The current state is the first page of the form.  When the user clicks "Next" button it goes to page 2 of the form.  I want to add a new set of controls that represents page 2.

What is the correct way to organize this in QtQuick / QML ?

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do that is with a StackView. The organization would be something like this:

```
Window {
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: page1
    }
    Item {
        id: footerItem
        // Maybe add other buttons here too
        Button {
            id: nextBtn
            text: "Next"
            onClicked: {
                stackView.push(page2);
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: page1
        Page1 {
             // Define this in separate Page1.qml file
             // This is where your page 1 controls go.
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: page2
        Page2 {
             // Define this in separate Page2.qml file
             // This is where your page 2 controls go.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably implement a mode changing view or form with "Back" and "Next" buttons using [StackLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html). The `StackLayout` class provides a stack of items where only one item is visible at a time. You go to the next or previous mode by updating `currentIndex`.

```
StackLayout {
    id: layout
    anchors.fill: parent
    currentIndex: 1
    Rectangle {
        color: 'teal'
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 200
    }
    Rectangle {
        color: 'plum'
        implicitWidth: 300
        implicitHeight: 200
    }
}
```